# Error running test using Robot Framework with Sikuli

Tags: python, automated-tests, robotframework, sikuli

I have a question/problem.
Could you help me?

I'm automating tests using Robot Framework with Sikuli.

When i run my first test, i get the following message:

`java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null`

**Log print:**
[image]

**My test:**
[image]

What could it be?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: anyone to help me?

Comment: check the comment #15 @ https://bugs.launchpad.net/sikuli/+bug/1797505 - might help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it very simply!

I just replaced the keyword "Run Process" with "Start Process".

Sorted out!